# Viewport Overlay behaves strange

Tags: mesh, topology

I am right now at a Re-topo in Blender 2.8 and somehow the overlay of the faces are not as the same place as shown. (see image)
[image]
The Object has a Shrinkwrap Modifier and in the view port "Display in front" is checked.
The snapping tool is activated as well as show overlay.

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature... Anyway it is confusing to work with :(

If I can turn it off somehow I would appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: On your shrinkwrap modifier is the Offset set to 0?

Comment: Hi. Please upload any images using the built-in image uploader as a) this prevents the answer being less clear should external links break and b) this shows the images inline. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Yes the modifier was at 0. I did it in an other version of blender.